# Problema para obtener SAMLResponse en aplicación .NET FRAMEWORK (con SHIBBOLETH)

Tags: asp.net, saml

Tengo una apli web, hecha con ASP .net Framework y publicada en IIS, que se valida con SAML a través de Shibboleth.

En las herramientas de Chrome veo que se recibe algo con el nombre de POST y que dentro está el Token que necesito. Pero cuando intento recogerlo en la aplicación, el valor es nulo.

He probado así:

```
string Token = Request.Form["SAMLResponse"];
```

y también así:

```
string Token;
using (StreamReader Lector = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
{ Token = Lector.ReadToEnd(); }
```

Pero, en ambos casos, el valor que recoge es nulo.

Aclaro que, si pruebo la apli en localhost, entonces sí que recojo el valor con `Request.Form["SAMLResponse"]`

¿Podéis decirme qué hago mal o cómo debería hacer para recoger la cadena del token?

Gracias.

Comment: Ya tengo la solución. Por si a alguien el es útil, aquí la dejo.

Comment: En primer lugar, ha quedado claro que el token es "interceptado" por Shibboleth y, por tanto, nunca va a poder llegar a la aplicación. Lo que hace Shibboleth es leer ese token y tomar los metadatos que se hayan definido. Por tanto, lo que la aplicación tiene que leer son las Request.ServerVariables que correspondan a esos metadatos.

En segundo lugar, si los metadatos siguen sin aparecer, a pesar de que estén bien mapeados, puede ser porque haya un problema de formato. En mi caso, en Azure Active Directory había que definir cada atributo con formato de nombre 'Básico'.